# How to create custom Live CD with upgraded linux-image kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, livecd

I'm following this tutorial to customize a Live CD,

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-live-cd

I have prepared the rootfs in a new created ext4 partition, after remove/install necessary packages, and `linux-image` is upgraded to `linux-image-2.6.35-24`,

```
# mv custom/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-24-generic tmpcd/casper/vmlinuz
# mv custom/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-24-generic tmpcd/casper/initrd
# lzma tmpcd/casper/initrd
# mv tmpcd/casper/initrd.lzma tmpcd/casper/initrd.lz
```

And, after created the ISO image and run in VirtualBox, I got the following error:

```
[    7.314180] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)
[    7.318550] Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tained 2.6.35-24-generic #42-Ubuntu
[    7.318857] Call Trace:
...
```

So, it looks like the upgraded vmlinuz image is successful located, but it's just not work.

I have searched google, but didn't find any resolution. any idea?

**EDIT**

I have a mistake, the file `initrd.img-2.6.35-24-generic` is already gzip-ped, so it should be decompressed before recompress with `lzma`:

```
# gunzip -c custom/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-24-generic | lzma > tmpcd/casper/initrd.lz
```

But it still failed to boot. I guess the `initrd` should be manually configured, because the system goes well with the original version of `vmlinuz`  and `initrd.lz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to look at **[Remastersys](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/remastersystool.html)**...Allows you to create a custom Live CD based on your Ubuntu or Debian Linux installation.

If you don't have Ubuntu/Debian installed, then get [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install as a virtual machine...

Tutorials here (2nd one was better):
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html
http://klikit.pbworks.com/Remastersys+tutorial+by+dedoimedo

Downloadable here:
http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/remastersystool.html

Answer (score 0):

I use turnkey linux tools for this...pretty handy and ubuntu based - looking for the link where they had a tutorial on making respins.

edit: http://wiki.turnkeylinux.org/Reference

giving studiohack a +1 for remastersys I just like turnkey tools better - opinion